# Minitest integration testing: session not tearing down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, capybara, minitest

I recently switched a very simple rails app from rspec to minitest. I also use capybara and factory_girl.

I have 3 separate integration test files, all of which involve logging the user in using something along the lines of:

```
before(:each) do
  user = Factory(:user)
  visit login_path
  fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
  fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
  click_button "Log in"
end
```

After I switched to minitest, it seems as if the sessions ceased to tear down after each test. For instance, I would test login using the above code in a test file named "users_integration_test.rb" and when it begins running another test file, say "sessions_integration_test.rb", the user is already logged in before I can log in again using the above code.

My question is: Is this an intentional difference between rspec and minitest, and I simply need to logout the user after each test? Or did I make a mistake setting up minitest?

I am using the same minitest_helper file as in the Minitest Railscast.

Comment: really, did you try logout? I think it will work

Comment: Yes I did try an after(:each) logout. It works fine at that point, but  my question is, I wonder if I had made a mistake setting up Minitest incorrectly, since I had though tearing down sessions would be automatic for a testing framework. It'd be a pain to have to tear down everything manually in my tests!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to tear down correctly with this. Hope it helps!
Mr. Maeshima's answer may very well work too. I have not tried.

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "minitest/autorun"
require "capybara/rails"
require "active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown"

Dir[Rails.root.join("test/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

class IntegrationTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
  register_spec_type(/integration$/, self)
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium

  after do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean       # Truncate the database
    Capybara.reset_sessions!    # Forget the (simulated) browser state
    Capybara.use_default_driver # Revert Capybara.current_driver to Capybara.default_driver
  end
end

class HelperTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown
  include ActionView::TestCase::Behavior
  register_spec_type(/Helper$/, self)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the difference but below code may work.

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "minitest/autorun"
require "capybara/rails"
require "active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown"

class IntegrationTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
  after do
    reset_session!
  end
  register_spec_type(/integration$/, self)
end

class HelperTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown
  include ActionView::TestCase::Behavior
  register_spec_type(/Helper$/, self)
end
```